# Perl emulating linux time command

Tags: linux, perl

I am writing a perl script, and I need to achieve the same output as the linux "time" command, but without actually using the "time" command.  Meaning I need to get the "real", "usr", "sys" times from a specific start time up to another point in time.

I have looked at the [`Time::HiRes`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time%3a%3aHiRes) library, but I am new to perl and am not sure how to use it properly.

How can I achieve the same output as the "time" command using `Time::HiRes`?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The breakdown of user and system time cannot be calculated from the elapsed wall time, which is the only information that Time::HiRes will give you.

You will need to use a module like [BSD::Resource](http://search.cpan.org/~jhi/BSD-Resource/Resource.pm) (specifically, the `getrusage()` function) to get this information.